# How to remove QWidget instance after closing its window?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt

Working on a basic GUI using PyQt.
I have a starting main window (QMainWindow).
By clicking on it, new window (QWidget) opens.
After clicking on it next window (QWidget) opens and so on.
Each QWidget contains, among other things, two buttons (but in my case labels): back and quit.

Back button (label) should just show previous window.
Quit button should delete all instances of QWidgets and just show starting main window without any previous instances of QWidgets present in memory.

My code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow, picturesPath):
        ....window properties...

        self.label.mousePressEvent = self.labelClicked
        self.nextWindow=None
        self.nextWindowInst=None

    def labelClicked(self, event):
        self.nextWindow=QtGui.QWidget()
        self.nextWindowInst=Ui_Widget1()
        self.nextWindowInst.setupUi(self.nextWindow)
        self.nextWindow.show()

class Ui_Widget1(QtGui.QWidget):

    def setupUi(self):
        ...window properties...
        self.labelStart.mousePressEvent = self.labelPocetakClicked

    def labelStartClicked(self, event):
        ...somehow to delete UI_Widget1 instance that was created in main window...

def main():
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow=QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui=Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like, when I click the label labelStart on instance of Ui_Widget1 to close the showing QWidget window, and also to delete the Ui_Widget1 instance.

Comment: self.deleteLater() ?

Comment: You're probably going about this in the wrong way: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20433522/984421) for a better alternative.